# Apache with mod_auth_openidc and Azure AD is not working

Tags: apache, azure-active-directory, mod-auth-openidc

I am setting up a legacy web application behind Apache.

I want to enable only authenticated users to access it and we are using Office 365 and we have Azure AD accounts.

We've decided that mod_auth_openidc can be a possible solution, but for some reason it is not working (yet;))

I am getting the following error from the module on `URL` "https://my.nice.server/secure/redirect_uri":

**Error:**

```
OpenID Connect Provider error: Error in handling response type.
```

This my Apache

**configuration:**

```
OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration 
OIDCClientID XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
OIDCClientSecret YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
OIDCRedirectURI https://my.nice.server/secure/redirect_uri
OIDCCryptoPassphrase ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
OIDCResponseType id_token
OIDCResponseMode form_post

<Location />
    AuthType openid-connect
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I tried to look at the sources of mod_auth_openidc but I couldn't sort out...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `OIDCProviderMetadataURL` should point specifically to your tenant so it should be something like:

`https://sts.windows.net/[TENANT_ID]/.well-known/openid-configuration`

See also: https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/wiki/Azure-OAuth-2.0-and-OpenID-Connect

Comment: Tenant ID which needed to be placed in the URI can be found as "Directory ID" under the AzureAD/Properties page. A bit confusing...